# How to generate table header with wicket

Tags: java, html, wicket

I want to generate this table header by wicket

```
<tr>
    <th>Actions</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Home Phone</th>
    <th>Cell Phone</th>
</tr>
```

where header names are saved in `arrayList`

I try something like this. It generate what I want but in html code it show warning

```
- Invalid location of tag (div).
```

Good thing is that div tag is not showed in generated html code. 
I dont know what tag should I use when I just want `th` without `span` tag

```
        <tr>
            <div wicket:id="seasonNames"><th wicket:id="season">[season]</th></div>
        </tr>
```

Comment: you can not add any html code inside <tr> directly rather than <th> and <td>. this is wrong

Comment: yes I know. But what is the right solution to add wicket component with id=seasonNames ?

Comment: Have seasonNames in <th>. any problem due to that?

Comment: yea because seasonNames is list of values but value is in component with id=season

Comment: but you need all seasons inside single <th>? right?

Comment: I need each season's name in separate th tag like first part of code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100132/discussion-between-hudi-and-janani).

Comment: Seems to me the wicket:id="seasonNames" needs to be on the TR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use DataTable component. In that case you have to pass a list of `IColumn` instances and use HeaderToolbar. See Wicket-examples for this approach.

Another way is to use simple repeater, like RepeatingView or ListView. In that case `wicket:id="seasonNames"` should be <wicket:container> instead of <div>.

Comment: seasonNames can not be on tr because then it will create list of tr elements but I want just 1 tr element